# Load modal every 5 min

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I Need to load a external html page with the modal every 5 min with ajax.

This is what i have now.

```
 <li><a href="modal.html" data-toggle="ajaxModal">open modal</a></li>
```

This works when i click on the link but i need it to open automatically every 5min

I found Other examples but there they didn't use ajax and the modal wasn't on a new page.
Something like this but then with a html page.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
$("#myDialog").dialog("open");
}, 30000);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or jQuery UI?

Comment: @PeterKA I use both jquery and bootstrap

Comment: can you put an id on the button and then click it? or find the attr ajaxModal and click it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('*[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').click();}
 ,30000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="modal.html" data-toggle="ajaxModal">open modal</a></li>
```

Comment: This is working only the css is not working anymore and i can´t close the modal.

Comment: Your css isn't working ? is there something in the modal with the same data attr?

Comment: It working now. one last question how can i check if its open? so it doesn;t open it again after 5 min. but only if it is closed

Comment: is the id of the modal myDialog ? if is put a if(!$('#myDialog')){......} Around the code that you use to open the dialog.not tested, let me know EDITED due to my shite coding, test again if not the edited version

Comment: When i add that it also doens't show the modal in the first time

Comment: try if($('#myDialog ').length <= 0){ //// it doesn't exist }

Comment: It keeps reloading it with that code even if it exists

Comment: Got it working for me. try this    if(document.getElementById('myDialog') instanceof Object){....it exists}else{..... it doesn't}

Comment: Nope still reopening :(

Comment: Isn't there a way to just close the modal after 4 min?

Comment: did that not work. Is your modal loading cross domain stuff or is it all from your domain?

Comment: Just a html file on my domain

Comment: I'm off to bed in a mo so i'm afraid you're on your own from here on in. The  way I would suggest  is put ` window.setTimeout(function () {
this.window.close();}, 3400);` in the modal so it closes itself. p.s let me know if it works....night night

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open a modal every 5 min you should use the `setInterval` instead `setTimeout`.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
}, 300000); //This value is represented in mili seconds.
```

If you also need load an html page inside your modal you need to make and AJAX request to load the page. You can do it easy with the **jQuery load** function.

```
$("#myDialog").load( "yourPage.html" );
```

Comment: I tried that but isn´t working it needs to include the html page with the modal code

Comment: I think you don´t understand me. The html page is the modal thats called by click with ajax at this moment. but I need to load it every 5 min